# Cannot resolve symbol - ArrayList, Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm writing a code in JAVA that is going to be a Lucky Wheel Game. The game at this stage takes a number as input to start the wheel to turn, get a random element from a collection of prizes and outputs the price. As you can see the code below, I created an array and added it's elements to the ArrayList. The player have 3 turns and at each turn he gets a random price (element) from the ArrayList. Sounds good, but I'm stuck. The problem is, for some reason I get the error of "Cannot resolve symbol 'wheel'. I use IntelliJ IDEA. I just started coding so I'm sure there's gonna be more errors after I resolve this one. But first, I want to solve this, then I can continue the game and add more to it. Thanks for all the answers!

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Game {
    public static void func1(String[] prizes) {
        ArrayList<String> wheel = new ArrayList<>(5);
        //Adds array elements to ArrayList
        Collections.addAll(wheel, prizes);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        String[] prizes = {"Television", "iPhone", "Microwave", "Ventilator", "Gift Card"};
        func1(prizes);

        int turn = scanner.nextInt(1);
        int tries = 0;
        int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(wheel.size());  // I get the error here
        //int wheel = wheel.size();

        while(tries < 3) {
            turn = scanner.nextInt(1);
            System.out.println("You won a" + wheel.get(index));  // and here too
            tries++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `wheel` is only defined inside of `func1`. `main` has no knowledge of it. That is called the variable's scope.

Comment: Thanks! I had the feeling it could be that! I was just wondering how can it be accessed from the method itself or can I have a duplicate ArrayList line in the code. I tried, now I have a different error. Going to solve it. Cheers!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but your `func1` can return the ArrayList and then you can access it in main